# Google translator Paid API Key issue

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I have integrated the google translator in my website. It was working fine.

After the restriction of free google option, i am using the following script with paid API key. It is working fine for the particular content (For example, div, span inner content)

How could i apply this script to whole webpage.

Is it possible to get the whole web page content ? Or any other option there to integrate google translator ?

```
<div id="sourceText">Some text to translate</div>
<div id="translation"></div>
<script>
  function translateText(response) {
    document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML = "<br>" + response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
  }
</script>
<script>
  var newScript = document.createElement('script');
  newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
  var sourceText = escape(document.getElementById("sourceText").innerHTML);
  var source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=MYAPIKEY=en&target='+tl+'&callback=translateText&q=' + sourceText;
  newScript.src = source;
  // When we add this script to the head, the request is sent off.
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
  </script>
```

Comment: You realize that most users will be annoyed if you use google translation on your webpage? Pretty much everyone prefers english over machine-translated *whatever*.

Comment: Agree with ThiefMaster, relying on Google to do the translations for you is a bad idea. A site translated with Google will never be taken seriously by anyone. Also retagged this post as your code is not related to PHP

Comment: okay.. thanks.. could you give any idea to translate my whole website with other languages?

Answer (score 0):

The Google translator API is used mostly for single fields or textarea's within a system. It's not really ment for translating whole pages. First of all there is a restriction for the amount of characters you're going to translate. It's most likely not even enough for your pages as HTML tags are processed as well. What you need is to have the Google Translator bar installed on your site, so users can select their language via a drop-down menu.

http://translate.google.com/translate_tools